# Android Webview page could not be loaded with HTTP hyperlink because ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm working on an android native app where I'm loading a HTML string in WebView from strings.xml which has some hyperlink texts all. One hyperlink out of all of them is having `http` url and which is not getting opened within webView and throwing error as `ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED`. I'm already using `usesCleartextTraffic` settings in my app but still unable to use that.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <application
    android:name=".com.app"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_hp_launcher"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_hp_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

**network_security_config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<debug-overrides>
    <trust-anchors>
        <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
        <certificates src="user" />
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
</debug-overrides>

<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config>

<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <!-- Make sure your URL Server here -->
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">https://xxxxxx.base.url</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://.xxxx.org</domain>
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="user"/>
        <certificates src="system"/>
    </trust-anchors>
</domain-config>
```

**UIClass.kt**

```
//Enabling JS for allowing all hyperlinks
    binding.webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    binding.webView.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
```

**build.gradle**

```
minSdkVersion 28
targetSdkVersion 30
```

Please let me know if I'm doing any mistake. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem by two options.

**Option 1:**

I removed one line from the `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

**Option 2:**

Added http legacy library in the `build.gradle` file under `defaultConfig` column as

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```